# Custom XLSX Sheet using JS

Tags: javascript, excel, xlsx, alasql

I'm working on a custom widget that exports data from Exosite IoT Platform on .csv and .xlsx files. It's working really fine, I can do all the selection, export data but I'd like to ask if you  can help me to change the way I get and show it on the sheet:

Today, it goes like this:

```
name | value | date | unit
Channel 1 | 20.5 | 5/3/2017 10:41 AM | ºC
Channel 1 | 22.5 | 5/3/2017 10:42 AM | ºC
Channel 1 | 19.5 | 5/3/2017 10:43 AM | ºC
Channel 2 | 18.5 | 5/3/2017 10:41 AM | ºC
Channel 2 | 23.5 | 5/3/2017 10:42 AM | ºC
```

I want to show like this:

```
Channel 1 | Channel 2 | date | unit
20.5 | 18.5 | 5/3/2017 10:41 AM | ºC
22.5 | 23.5 | 5/3/2017 10:42 AM | ºC
19.5 | 20.5 | 5/3/2017 10:43 AM | ºC
20.5 | 20.5 | 5/3/2017 10:44 AM | ºC
20.5 | 20.5 | 5/3/2017 10:45 AM | ºC
```

My .js function that edits this is:

```
   processData:function(){
        this.dataToExport=[];
        var dataToExport=this.dataToExport;
        var i,
          j,
          k,
          date,
          dateFormat,
          value,
          unit,
          data;
        // collect output data
        k = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < resources.length; i++) {
          if (resources[i].isEnabled()) {
            for (j = 0; j < resources[i].data.length; j++) {
              date = new Date(resources[i].data[j][0] * 1000);
              dateFormat = '';
              dateFormat += date.toLocaleTimeString() + ' ';
              dateFormat += date.toDateString();
              value = resources[i].data[j][1];
              try {
                if (typeof JSON.parse(value) === 'object') {
                  value = $('<span/>')
                    .attr('title', value)
                    .text('More data');
                }
              } catch (e) {}
              unit = JSON.parse(resources[i].info.description.meta).datasource.unit;
              dataToExport[k] = {
                date: dateFormat,
                value: value,
                name: resources[i].info.description.name,
                unit: unit
              };
              k++;
            }
          }
        }
    },
    dataToExport:[],
    exportData:function(fileExtension){
        alasql("SELECT * INTO " + fileExtension + "('exportedData." + fileExtension + "',{headers:true}) FROM ?", [this.dataToExport]);
    }
```

I'm working with alaSQL to do this, but any help would be really great! I'm working with javascript recently and I feel some difficulties yet...

I believe that I need to filter and order the timestamps of the datasources, like a list on C++ and apply TList, for example (don't know if there's a command like that on JS). It should create a table with number of lines equal to the size of this list and number of columns equal to channel quantity + 1 (timestamp). On each line I put a timestamp, I have to look for an equal timestamp and insert the value of the channel related to this.